# C# e.Fullname without the extension

Tags: c#

When I use `e.Fullname` or `e.Name` on a file, it gives me the full name + extension, but I just want the  name of the file without like:".txt" after the name.

How do I show just the file name without the extension behind it? Is there a particular code for it?

Do I have to get the extension from the `e.fullname` apart and just use the piece that remains as the name without extension? Which one of these should I do?

Like at this:

```
 private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("File changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);

        name = e.Name;
        extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
        size = e.Name.Length;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if we knew what type of object `e` was.

Comment: system cannot exactly identify the ext of a file, for example .paf.exe(together) is a ext, but system can only fine the .exe as ext, you have to know what kind of files you are working and just remove the desire ext with some simple String ops

Answer (score 14):

`System.IO.Path` has a [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method which sounds like it does what you're looking for:

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

Comment: ^ this. `var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);`

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear which API you are using but it seems that you have a file name in the e.Fullname variable.

To clean up the file name you can use methods from the [System.IO.Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx). In your case you would use the [System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method.